# I am working on comparing and subtracting values from multiple Arrays

Tags: javascript

I'm working on a project where I have multiple variables, usually 3 to 6, and each variable has 2 values (placed in an array). I need to compare and subtract value 1 of Variable X to value 2 of Variable Y, and value 1 of Variable Y to value 2 of Variable Z and so on.

How would I accomplish this? (Bonus points if you tell me how to modify the numbers in the arrays before comparing them. How do you modify only a single value in a string and not the whole string itself?)

Here are some examples of a few variables:

```
let p17 = ["2", "4"];

let p33 = ["3", "3"];

let p64 = ["5", "6"];

let p28 = ["6", "2"];
```

> `p17`'s 2 goes to `p28`'s 2, equaling 0. 
> `p33`'s 3 goes to `p17`'s 4, equaling -1. 
> `p64`'s 5 goes to `p33`'s 3, equaling 2. 
> and `p28`'s 6 goes to `p64`'s 6, equaling 0.

Note: I have 136 variables in this project that need to follow this formula, variables being pulled randomly (but I can work the rng part out).

Comment: What is the expected output? An array of the differences `[0, -1, 2, 0]`?

Comment: Also, you should probably have an array of arrays like `[ ["2", "4"], ["3", "3"], ...]` and pull 4 random items out of these for processing. Instead of having 136 separate variables.

Answer (score -1):

i second adiga, use nested arrays. the pseudocode i would use is:

- define the p array (put p17, p33, etc here as p[17], p[33], etc)
- define the first variable and second variable (i'll use "num1" and "num2" here)
- use p[num1][0] minus p[num2][1] as a variable definition or put it in a conditional or whatever you wanted to do with this information
- redefine num1 and num2 to whatever numbers you want next, and repeat

as for modifying array items, they can be redefined like variables. just type p[17] = new Array(2, 4) or whatever. arrays aren't strings, strings are text. arrays are just a way to put multiple variables in one place, which is convenient when the variable you need depends on the situation. (using a variable in place of an index number will refer to whatever index number that variable's value is)